# Passing additional arguments to function call (lodash)

Tags: javascript, scope, lodash

Relating to the following mock code (_ relates to the lodash library):

```
var containerFunction = function () {
    var opts = {data: value};
    _.map(lines, functionForEach);
}

var functionForEach = function (line) {
  Do something for each line passed in from the maps function.
  Need to access opts in this scope.
  return value;
}
```

The argument line is received from the map function, but what would be the best way of passing the opts argument to the functionForEach function while keeping the rough pattern above (if possible).

I thought something like:

```
_.map(lines, functionForEach(opts))
```

or something similar might work but obviously doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put `functionForEach` inside `containerFunction`. If you must, pass `opts` as the third `context` (`thisArg`) argument to `_.map` and access it using `this` inside `functionForEach`.

Comment: I didn't want to nest the function as I get the impression its frowned upon from a performance and memory perspective.

Comment: Where did you get such an impression? Even if that were the case, which it's not, the first priority should be getting nice clean code working, then worry about performance.

Comment: I was reading about this earlier. Correct me if I'm wrong, but nested functions result in each nested function being created and destroyed every time the parent function is called. I know it probably doesn't make a lot of difference unless the code is being run on a large scale system, but I'm trying to factor in as many considerations as I go...

Comment: Today's engine optimizations mean you don't have to worry about such things if in fact they were ever an issue. It's always puzzled me why folks relatively early in their JS learning curve spend so much time worrying about performance questions, most of which are based on urban myths.

Comment: Well I don't think they're "urban myths" as such, but possibly irrelevant based on engine optimisation as you say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have three alternatives:

1. Put `functionForEach` inside `containerFunction`. If you are not going to use `functionForEach` elsewhere, this makes the most sense.
2. Write it as:

   ```
   var containerFunction = function () {
     var opts = {data: value};
     _.map(lines, function(elt) { return functionForEach(elt, opts); });
   }

   var functionForEach = function (line, opts) {
     Do something for each line passed in from the maps function.
     Need to access opts in this scope.
     return value;
   }
   ```

3. If you must, pass `opts` as the third (`thisArg`) argument to `_.map` and access it using `this` inside `functionForEachvar`.

Answer (score 5):

Lodash has good utilities for function composition, including partially-applying arguments. However, this isn't actually so straightforward. Let's say we want to use [partialRight()](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight):

```
function functionForEach(item, i) { return item * i; }

_.map([1, 2, 3], _.partialRight(functionForEach, 2));
// → [0, 2, 6]
```

Oops. That's not correct. The reason is that we're not getting the arguments passed to `functionForEach()` as we expect them. We want the `i` argument to always have a value of `2` and the `item` is the mapped collection value.

Let's try something else:

```
_.map([1, 2, 3], _.ary(_.partialRight(functionForEach, 2), 1));
// → [2, 4, 6]
```

That's better. The problem is that [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) passes the item as the first argument, along with 2 other arguments (the index and the collection itself). Since we don't care about these latter two arguments, we can use [ary()](https://lodash.com/docs#ary) to compose a new function that ignores them.

Here's another approach:

```
_.map([1, 2, 3], _.partial(_.rearg(functionForEach, 1, 0), 2));
// → [2, 4, 6]
```

This time, we're using [rearg()](https://lodash.com/docs#rearg) to change the order of our [partial()](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) function arguments. This approach I find to be less intuitive than simple going right for `partialRight()`.

One final example:

```
_.map([1, 2, 3], _.flow(_.identity, _.partialRight(functionForEach, 2)));
// → [2, 4, 6]
```

Here, we're using the [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs#flow) higher-order function to compose our callback. This function takes the arguments supplied to it, and chains together the functions we pass to it - the output of the last function is the input to the next. We're using the [identity()](https://lodash.com/docs#identity) function here because it simply returns the first argument passed to it, which is exactly what we want.

This last approach is similar to the `ary()` approach - it's doing the same thing. The `flow()` approach is superior if we ever wanted to build on this behavior by passing in more functions, before or after `functionForEach()`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `_.partial`. Docs:

[partial](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#partial)

```
var containerFunction = function() {
  var opts = { data: value };
  _.map(lines, _.partial(functionForEach, opts));
};

var functionForEach = function (opts, line) { ... };
```

`_.partial` returns a new function with the arguments prepended to the functionForEach. In the example above, `_.partial` returns the following function signature:

```
function (line) { ... }
```

Calling the return function with a line calls functionForEach with line and opts defaulted to whatever you passed in as the argument in `_.partial`.